Separating game logic from UI in lockstep multiplayer
In lockstep multiplayer the simulation of game world has to be deterministic. A frequent source of errors is accidentally changing the game state from local player UI functions. This breaks the deterministic simulation because other players in multiplayer did not do that UI interaction at same time, resulting in different world state.
For example: local player in multiplayer clicks something in UI. I want to show a particle effect as a visual response. I call GetRandomPosition() and forget that this is a simulation-only method. Now the local player has messed up their random number generation because they took +1 entry from the deterministic RNG generator. Everyone else will be 1 entry behind compared to the local player, causing desynchronization of the multiplayer game.
I could try to always remember what functions do what but there must be a better way to enforce separation. Should I split them into two namespaces? Separate assemblies?
The UI needs to see the game state but be unable to change it.

Local functions should not have the power in the first place to do such calls. Always queue to the server and the server handles when/ how the rnd seeds gets called/ increasest. That should be done for any other function as well.

This is standard in non-lockstep multiplayer but with lockstep each client makes these decisions locally. This allows more decisions to be made than a server-authority solution allows while giving up protection against client side hacking. In some applications that's a good tradeoff, for example in RTS games. For example Age of Empires and Starcraft series.

Isnt lockstep more about that you just send the inputs that control that system with a timestep and all actions are performed in order of timestamp? So if you do not have a central server, you would still queue your own actions and you can't really desync the seed
